# Do not display a color if there is no color name (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I get the name of the frame color for the picture from Model() the color I take from colorSet

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let image: String
    let colorSet: String

}

extension Model {
    
    static func AllModel() -> [Model] {
        
        return [
            //1
            Model(image: "folder", colorSet: "YELLOW"),
            //2
            Model(image: "folder.fill",  colorSet: "")
            
        ]
        
    }
}
```

But if the colorSet doesn't have a color name because it's not needed, I get an error
[image]

how to make that if a color name is not in the colorSet, then nothing is displayed

**full code**

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let image: String
    let colorSet: String

}

extension Model {
    
    static func AllModel() -> [Model] {
        
        return [
            //1
            Model(image: "folder", colorSet: "YELLOW"),
            //2
            Model(image: "folder.fill",  colorSet: "")
            
        ]
        
    }
}


struct Im: View {
    
    let model = Model.AllModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
        ForEach(model) { model in

           CellView(model: model)
        }
        
        }
    }
}


struct CellView: View {

    
    let model: Model
    
    var body: some View {

        Image(systemName: model.image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
            .stroke(Color(model.colorSet), lineWidth: 5))

    }

    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Make `colorSet` optional and test to see whether it is non-nil and if it is nil, use `.clear`.  The same problem would occur if you passed in a color name that doesn't actually exist in the color palette. You could also just default to clear in for `colorSet`.

Comment: I need a frame color not for all images, I'm new, how do I do that?

Comment: `.clear` IS a frame color, but it won't be visible when displayed.

Comment: Also, do you have the color "YELLOW' defined as a color in your Assets?

Comment: You do not understand my question, look at the image at the bottom of the question and you will see that the frame is yellow. So I have that color. My question is that if I don't need to show the color - how can I do that.  for example I have 20 images in Model() and I only need to show the frame color on 5 images

Comment: You do not understand my answer. If you don't want to display the frame in a color around the icon, make a color "Clear" and use that. Otherwise, we start talking about writing view modifiers. Or, you can make `colorSet` an optional and substitute `.clear` if it is nil. Do not get wrapped up in having a "color" with no opacity. We have one built in to SwiftUI for this very reason.

Comment: Is it not possible to make a function that if there is a color name - then show this color, if there is no color name, then do not show color

Comment: How do I make the colorSet optional then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243193/discussion-between-yrb-and-dmitriy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear:

```
extension Model {
    
    static func AllModel() -> [Model] {
        return [
            //1
            Model(image: "folder", colorSet: "YELLOW"),
            //2
            Model(image: "folder.fill",  colorSet: "CLEAR")
        ]
    }
}
```

Set a "CLEAR" colorSet like this:

[image: Image showing how to set clear color]

As a result, you would get this:

[image: Image showing result of code with yellow frame and clear frame]

Edit:

Since your are ALSO displaying the name of the color below the icon, all you need to do is use a ternary to see if `colorSet == "CLEAR"` and then substitute an empty string for it like this:

```
struct CellView: View {
    let model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Image(systemName: model.image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
            .stroke(Color(model.colorSet), lineWidth: 5))
            // Put a ternary in the Text() to test whether you have "CLEAR"
            Text(model.colorSet == "CLEAR" ? "" : model.colorSet)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already done so, but under the name of the picture I display the name of the color, and where there is no frame with the color I get the name Clear. I missed the point and didn't write it in the question

Comment: That was not your original question. I have edited the answer. Your question did not say the color was displayed. Please make sure all relevant information is in a question, or ask another question. See [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be more careful next time)

Answer (score 0):

I would make your model richer so your view is simpler

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let image: String
    let colorSet: String?  // optional named color
}

extension Model {
    static func AllModel() -> [Model] {
        return [
            //1
            Model(image: "folder", colorSet: "YELLOW"),
            //2
            Model(image: "folder.fill",  colorSet: nil)
        ]
    }

    // Computed property for the color
    var borderColor: Color {
        guard let colorSet = colorSet else {
            return .clear
        }

        return Color(colorSet)
    }

    // and e.g. for a name for showing in the UI
    var uiName: String {
        guard let colorSet = colorSet else {
            return "None"
        }

        return colorSet
    }
}
```

Then your view becomes

```
struct CellView: View {
    let model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: model.image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .padding()
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 9)
                    .stroke(model.borderColor, lineWidth: 5)
                )
    }
}
```

Similarly for text, with the name formatted for display in the model, not in the view.